# Pandas dataframe Auto-adjust column witdth when set format to header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, format, xlsxwriter

I'm using this code to dinamicaly adjust the column width of an excel using pandas:

```
for column in df:
  column_width = max(df[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
  col_idx = df.columns.get_loc(column)
  writer.sheets['Sheet1'].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_width)
```

And it works. But when I want to give format to the header:

```
header_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'border': 1, 'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 12, 'bold': True, 'italic': True})
```

The text is cut. It's like the width adjust to the content, but if I resize the font_size it won't adjust. I tried setting the column format after and before adjusting the width.

How can I auto-adjust the column width based not only in his value, also in his font size?

Comment: You will need to add a more complete example or at least update the question to show how the first and second snippet are related.